# Build Error when compiling YCSB: "Error reading assemblies"

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin, build-error, ycsb

I am trying to compile the YCSB Project with the `clean package` command. The project is downloaded from the github site as a .zip, got unzipped and no changes have been made.
I get an Build Error when compiling that says:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'datastore-specific-assembly' not found
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error reading assemblies: Descriptor with ID 'datastore-specific-assembly' not found
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:453)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.AssemblyReadException: Descriptor with ID 'datastore-specific-assembly' not found
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.addAssemblyForDescriptorReference(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.io.DefaultAssemblyReader.readAssemblies(DefaultAssemblyReader.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:449)
    ... 19 more
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same error as you. You should file an issue with your stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my Problem. I was using an old Maven version, which is not supported anymore. Currently Maven 3 is needed to compile. Chech with your Maven version with `mvn -version`.

To update Maven to another version follow the commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove <YOUR MAVEN VERSION>
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven
```